# C - is it necessary to check freopen return value?

Tags: c, gcc

The signature for freopen is `FILE * freopen ( const char * filename, const char * mode, FILE * stream )`

According to the docs, the return value is the same as what `stream` is set to.  So, my code already checks `stream != 0`, do I need to check the return value? How could `stream == 0` but `retval != 0`? If I don't need to check both, why does gcc give me a warning if I don't check the retval?

To quiet gcc, is it okay to simply do: `stream = freopen(filename, mode, stream); if (!stream) {...})`?

Comment: I'm not sure how you are using it, but the primary use of the freopen() function is to change the file associated with a standard text stream (`stderr`, `stdin`, or `stdout`).

Comment: If there was no need to check the return value, there would be no need for the function to return a value. Since it does, the answer is clearly *Yes, you need to check it*.

Answer (score 5):

If it fails, it's not going to magically set the original stream variable (which it has no reference to, since the parameter is `FILE *` not `FILE **`) to NULL, so you do need to check the return value.

Answer (score 4):

You said:

> According to the docs, the return value is the same as what stream is set to.

Not according to http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/freopen

> **Return value**
>   1) A copy of the value of stream on success, null pointer on failure.

You asked:

> do I need to check the return value?

Yes, you should, always. `freopen` can fail for all the reasons that `fopen` can fail -- permissions, non-existent directory, too many open files, etc. It is a good practice to always check the return value of `freopen` before you use it.